# How to define an array of numbers with a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a project where I need to break people into 3 buckets with task lists that rotate quarterly (Phase A = task list 1, B = task list 2, C = task list 3).  The goal here is to sort people into the buckets based on a departure date, with the ideal being that they would depart when they're in the C phase.  I have a formula already set up that will tell me the number of quarters between the project start date and the person's departure date, so now I'm trying to figure out how to get Excel to tell me if a person's departure date falls within their bucket's C Phase.

I have this formula in a column called `DEROSQtr`:`=ROUNDDOWN(DAYS360("1-Oct-2020",[@DEROS],FALSE)/90,0)`

Now the easy way to approach this would be to build a static array and just see if that formula results in a value in the right array, where the numbers in the array define which quarter from Oct 2020 that the bucket's C Phase is going to be in:
`ArrayA = {1;4;7;10;13;16} ArrayB = {2;5;8;11;14;17} ArrayC = {0;3;6;9;12;15}`

The formula that pulls this all together is then:

`=IF([@EFP]="A",IF(IFNA(MATCH([@DEROSQtr],ArrayA,0),-1)<>-1,TRUE,FALSE),IF([@EFP]="B",IF(IFNA(MATCH([@DEROSQtr],ArrayB,0),-1)<>-1,TRUE,FALSE),IF([@EFP]="C",IF(IFNA(MATCH([@DEROSQtr],ArrayC,0),-1)<>-1,TRUE,FALSE),"-")))`

Now while this will work for as long as I build out the static array, I'm trying to figure out how to define each of these buckets with a formula that Excel can work with, i.e. bucket A hits phase C in `3n + 1` quarters where `n` is the number of cycles through all 3 phases, so `ArrayA = 3n+1`, `ArrayB = 3n+2` and `ArrayC = 3n`.  What I'm hunting for here is the best way to define each of the arrays as a formula.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional digging and looking back at how to define each array, I came across the `MOD()` function in Excel.  I was then able to rewrite the formula that does the checking as `=IF([@EFP]="A",IF(MOD([@DEROSQtr]-1,3)=0,TRUE,FALSE),IF([@EFP]="B",IF(MOD([@DEROSQtr]-2,3)=0,TRUE,FALSE),IF([@EFP]="C",IF(MOD([@DEROSQtr],3)=0,TRUE,FALSE),"-")))`, replacing `ArrayA`(3n+1) with `MOD([@DEROSQtr]-1,3)`, `ArrayB`(3n+2) with `MOD([@DEROSQtr]-2,3)`, and `ArrayC`(3n) with `MOD([@DEROSQtr],3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the data you are calculating your quarter, its difficult to give you exact answer. However, as I understand your have a column which has the formula to calculate the quarter say "Formula_Col"

Solution will be to add a new column and flag it based on the values in "Formula_Col".

If you can give some sample data I can provide exact answer.

Comment: For sample data, literally throw a dart at a random calendar date in the future (or use `=NOW()+(RAND()*1000)`).  I've corrected the formula for determining number of quarters between date and project start (1-Oct-2020).  I'll edit the post to better define the question at hand, which is how to define the arrays.